# chart.js toggleDatasetVisibility and getDatasetVisibility doesn't work

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to toggle data set visibility from outside of my chart. Using `setDatasetVisibility` to explicitly set viability works fine with two buttons, one to set it to true and the other to false.

While `setDatasetVisibility` will indeed hide and show the data set, `getDatasetVisibility` continues to return true regardless of the current visibility.

The `toggleDatasetVisibility` method doesn't hide anything, but it does change the state of `getDatasetVisibility` which now returns the correct value.

Why is it that in order to make this work I need to do something like this? I would expect `toggleDataVisibility` to be sufficient.

```
lineChart.toggleDataVisibility(1);
lineChart.setDatasetVisibility(1, lineChart.getDataVisibility(1));
lineChart.update();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oxywhtdv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `toggleDatasetVisibility` is not a function, as you show in your code you are using `toggleDataVisibility` and this is according to the docs only valid for chart types which support hiding single elements.

The line chart does not support to hide a single dot from a line so you can't use the `toggleDataVisibility` for your use case.

You can use `getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).hidden` to check if the dataset is hidden (note this prop only gets set after it gets updated once)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Show Set 2" onclick="restoreLayer2()">
  <input type="button" value="Hide Set 2" onclick="removeLayer2()">
</div>
<script>
  lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [
        '10:00 AM',
        '11:00 AM',
        '12:00 PM',
        '1:00 PM',
        '2:00 PM',
        '3:00 PM',

        '4:00 PM',
        '5:00 PM',
        '6:00 PM',
        '7:00 PM',
        '8:00 PM',
        '9:00 PM'
      ],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Temperature',
        data: [
          74,
          77,
          80,
          82,
          86,
          85,

          83,
          79,
          72,
          68,
          66,
          66
        ],
      }, {
        label: 'Humidity',
        data: [
          44,
          44,
          45,
          45,
          45,
          46,

          46,
          46,
          45,
          44,
          44,
          44
        ],
      }],
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function restoreLayer2() {
    console.log(lineChart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden);

    lineChart.setDatasetVisibility(1, true);
    lineChart.update();
  }

  function removeLayer2() {
    console.log(lineChart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden);

    lineChart.setDatasetVisibility(1, lineChart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden);

    lineChart.update();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I guess it was late and I was definitely conflating DataVisibility and DatasetVisibility.